# Background audio not working

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a few pages and one of the pages is a library page. On that library page i get songs that are deserialized from a php file on my website and that php file requests song title, artist name etc from a mysql database.

Everything works fine when i try to add the songs to the itemGridView. Everything works fine when i select a song from the itemGridView(Background on Windows phone 10 and Windows 10 ).

The problem is that when I try to switch from track the transport controls are stuck and after 2 seconds it vanishes. Did i do something wrong? I just copied everything from the background sample.

Here is my code when i add the songs to the gridView:

```
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    public start()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // Limit the max buffer size for the response so we don't get overwhelmed
        httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
         this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required; 
        Instance = this;
        Loaded += Start_Loaded;     
        initializeSongs();
        backgroundAudioTaskStarted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        itemGridView.ItemsSource = Songs;
    }


async void initializeSongs()
    {
        try
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.myproductsofficial.eu/testt.php");
            string array = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string json = array;
            MessageDialog mes = new MessageDialog(json);
            await mes.ShowAsync();
            var xdd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
            foreach (var xd in xdd)
            {
                var song = new SongModel();
                song.Title = xd.SongName;
                song.Artist = xd.ArtistName;
                song.Listens = xd.Listens;
                song.AlbumArtUri = new Uri(xd.Thumbnail);
                song.MediaUri = new Uri(xd.MediaLink);
                Songs.Add(song);

            }
            foreach (var song in Songs)
            {
                var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.UriSource = song.AlbumArtUri;
                albumArtCache[song.AlbumArtUri.ToString()] = bitmap;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageDialog mes = new MessageDialog(e1.Message);
            mes.ShowAsync();
        }

    }

   private void itemGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var song = itemGridView.SelectedItem as SongModel;
        Debug.WriteLine("Clicked item from App: " + song.MediaUri.ToString());

        // Start the background task if it wasn't running
        if (!IsMyBackgroundTaskRunning || MediaPlayerState.Closed == BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.CurrentState)
        {
            // First update the persisted start track
            ApplicationSettingsHelper.SaveSettingsValue(ApplicationSettingsConstants.TrackId, song.MediaUri.ToString());
            ApplicationSettingsHelper.SaveSettingsValue(ApplicationSettingsConstants.Position, new TimeSpan().ToString());

            // Start task
            StartBackgroundAudioTask();
        }
        else
        {
            // Switch to the selected track
            MessageService.SendMessageToBackground(new TrackChangedMessage(song.MediaUri));
        }

        if (MediaPlayerState.Paused == BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.CurrentState)
        {
            BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
        }
    }
```

I checked if the app is going into suspended mode and the resuming modes. I also checked the declaration tab for background audio, the entry point is: BackgroundAudioTask.MyBackgroundAudioTask

Screenshot of projects: http://prntscr.com/81mrlq
BackgroundAudioTask: Windows Runtime Component
BackgroundAudioShared: Class Library(DLL)

Comment: Please specify your problems, this is way too broad. [Look here how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Plus SO is not really intended to find a "Teacher". If you can narrow your questions down like described in the link above, people can likely help you. You might have to ask more than one question though. Also specific questions might have been already answered which is often helpful because they went through editing and are likely higher quality in regards to questions and answers. Try using the search, you would be surprised how often you can find something.

Comment: @FrankJ Look frank i asked way too many questions and didn't got a single answer!!!

Comment: @FrankJ Updated it. Better?

Comment: @Christos not getting an answer is a rather strong indicator that the questions aren't well written, but not bad enough to attract downvotes or be closed. They are simply ignored, which may be worse. You should *really* read the guide to writing a good question, if you want to attract answers. Paragraphs, punctuation, avoiding fluff also helps

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes but is my post really hard to understand, I mean: All i want is to have that background audio task to function well!

Comment: First, it was unreadable. It was impossible to even find the question in that single continuous paragraph. Even after reformatting it, it seems you haven't posted the *relevant* code. What does "when I try to switch from track the transport controls are stuck" mean? Where is the relevant code? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Alright so when i click on the gridView item it plays the song fine. But when i try to switch from song(Click on a other song) then the transport controls just don't change and then they vanish!

Comment: PS: `async void` is evil and should *never* be used, except in event handlers. It means "fire-and-forget-and-crash-my-app-if-I-fail"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is there maybe a way we can discuss this on Skype? And i can detail it further with some more and better information and some screenshos.

Comment: @Christos repeating the same sentence doesn't help either. What transport controls? Where is the code that executes when you click on a different song? *Did you try debugging it?*

Comment: Transport controls: http://prntscr.com/81vsnv

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos or SystemMediaTransportControls how others call them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hey i fixed it. What the problem was: When i switched from track, there was some invalid characters in the Uri of the Album art, so i replaced the uri with a local ms-appx image and now it works fine.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering an old question here. With the Win10 Anniversary Update (build 14393) we have significantly simplified the model for background media playback.

MSDN doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio

Sample app:
[https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlaybackhttps://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback)

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform